# Tomcat library eager loading of jars

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, classloader

I have two applications deployed on a `Tomcat server (v7)` , both the applications use same shared library. I wanted to reduce the permgen memory foot print of these apps on JVM so I decided to take the common shared library out of the individual wars and put it in the `tomcat library folder`.

However this experiment backfired as the `ClassLoader` is per application context even though I moved the libraries to `tomcat lib`, shared library is getting loaded into the context of both the apps, worse it is getting loaded into the context of other apps that do not use this shared library.

Is there a way to load the library only once across the contexts in the web server?

I understand the risks of thread safety and security, those risks are mitigated in my case.

Comment: I am afraid there isn't. Sorry.

Comment: Is your shared library so big that memory consumption becomes a concern?

Comment: @dimoniy yes around 30 MB, I said 2 apps as an example but we are growing and new apps are getting added with same shared library(ies).

Comment: @Puru-- maybe then you should extract your library into a web service and just deploy and use it locally. There will be overhead on calls and development costs. One other alternative would be RCP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes from jars in the Tomcat lib directory get their own class loader which is shared amongst all deployed applications.

As you have noted each individual application also has it's own class loader.

At this point it's important to understand where Tomcat finds classes for each application. To paraphrase [Apache Tomcat Class Loader HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html), application classes are located in the following order:

1. JVM bootstrap classes
2. System classes
3. /WEB-INF/classes of the application
4. /WEB-INF/lib/*.jar classes
5. Common class loader (being jars in the "Tomcat lib" directory)

Items 1,2 & 5 above are separate class loaders with their own repository. Items 3 & 4 are a single class loader, but there is a separate one for each web-app.

Therefore, if you have copied your library jar into the Tomcat lib directory, and not removed it from your web-app then you will still be loading and using the jar in your web-app. Double check the deployment to ensure that the library jar is in fact no longer present in the WEB-INF/lib directory of each app.

Comment: you are right I found the same after reading the Apache docs. I am definitely sure that I removed jar from the war file. What I did not understand is the increased memory usage. When this shared library was inside the WAR tomcat was using 120 MB memory and as soon as I moved the shared libraries to lib, memory usage increased to 200 MB. This gave me a feeling that it was loading the class definitions for each web context in permgen?